# The requested resource () is not available. - iframe pdf

Tags: html, jsf, iframe, facelets

Inside of iframe I get the error message :

```
HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

descriptionThe requested resource () is not available.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2
```

I have placed a pdf in the folder resources/pdf/1.pdf and it does not matter where I place this file, I get this error, what have I done wrong or forgotten to do, it is a page that just shows the user an instruction manual.

```
<iframe src="/resources/pdf/1.pdf"></iframe>

|
| Gui
| `---- submittedPDF.xhtml
|
|
|resources
  `pdf
    `1.pdf
```

Heres a print screen of the structure

http://i1081.photobucket.com/albums/j348/west-wot/directory_zpsf8b3b5aa.png

Comment: Hard to say without knowing your directory structure from the web root.  Is `resources` a directory directly within the main web root directory?

Comment: Yes, i shall update the question with my directory now, sorry for not including that detail

Comment: added in the question above

Comment: So is `Gui` a directory inside your web root?  If so you need your source to be `/Gui/resources/pdf/1.pdf`

Comment: Gui is a directory of root, and the xhtml file is in this folder, resources is also a directory of root, and the pdf file is in this folder but the resource folder is not inside of GUI

Comment: If Gui is a directory of root where your html file containing the iframe is, and resources is too, your path should be: "../resources/pdf/1.pdf". the double dots ('..') means "go up one directory"

Comment: perfect the double dots worked :) thanks a lot

Comment: Please don't overgeneralize Facelets as XHTML. Facelets is XHTML, but XHTML is not Facelets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your code in the submittedPDF.xhtml to

```
<iframe src="../resources/pdf/1.pdf"></iframe>
```

`..` and `.` have following meanings in file paths: 
`..` means up one directory and `.` means current directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe src="/resources/pdf/1.pdf"></iframe>
```

The leading slash brings you to the domain root, skipping the context path.

You need to include the context path:

```
<iframe src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/pdf/1.pdf"></iframe>
```

Or, as it's apparently been placed in `/resources` folder, use the implicit `#{resource}` map:

```
<iframe src="#{resource['pdf/1.pdf']}"></iframe>
```

Either way, it'll autogenerate the proper domain-relative URL, including the context path.